# Initialize a service without a constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, internationalization

I'm trying to add i18n (integrated with ngx-translate) to my side menu, which is a constant object with each item inside

I've tried importing the i18n service and then declaring it as a variable to use it inside the object:

```
import { Menu } from './menu.model';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

let translate: TranslateService;

export const verticalMenuItems = [

    new Menu(1, translate.instant('MENU.DASHBOARD'), '/', null, 'dashboard', null, false, 0),
]
```

It won't get recognized as a service throwing the error

Cannot read property 'instant' of undefined

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just declaring a variable of type `TranslateService`, which is uninitialized. You don't actually have an instance of the service in translate. I would suggest **injecting** the service into the constructor of the component where you are declaring your constant. I would do something like this.

```
export class ExampleClass {

    verticalMenuItems: any;
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
        this.verticalMenuItems =
            [new Menu (1, translate.instant('MENU.DASHBOARD'), '/', null, 'dashboard', null, false, 0);
    }
}
```